# Can't seem to set environmental variables in fish correctly?

Tags: fish, llvm, clang

this is my fish configuration:

```
set -x CGO_CPPFLAGS 'llvm-config --cppflags'
set -x CGO_LDFLAGS 'llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs all'
set -x CGO_CXXFLAGS '-std=c++11'
```

I've tried running make on my LLVM-based project, but I get the following error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--cppflags'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this an error in my configuration file? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the variables to the output of llvm-config using command substitutions, rather than the raw commands themselves:

```
set -x CGO_CPPFLAGS (llvm-config --cppflags | tr -s ' ' \n)
set -x CGO_LDFLAGS (llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs all | tr -s ' ' \n)
set -x CGO_CXXFLAGS '-std=c++11'
```

The pipe through `tr` is to avoid getting bitten by [a difference in behaviour between bash/zsh and fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128669/fish-command-substitution-doesnt-work-like-in-bash-or-zsh).